# Apple Lazy Loading Images within a nav controller, reverts back to placeholder images

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I implemented the LazyTableImages project ([link](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394)) by Apple, but in my version I used RestKit to obtain the data and my UItableviewcontroller was push onto navigation stack.

So I eschew whatever apple does in the app delegate to get the xml. I dont think that's the problem. My problem is that when you back out of the UITableviewcontroller using either the nav back button or accessing another tabbar item and coming back, the images that were loaded there previously show up, but immediately it loads the placeholder image. Basically, the opposite happens.

It's like the UITableview cached data, so when you come back it interferes with the Lazy Table Images. I need to know has anyone implemented this code where they had to back out?

EDIT:

Looks like imageDownloader is not nil the second time, which prevents the image from loading. I'm still figuring out how to bypass it. Of course, I can just take out the condition, but I dont know if that is "bad" for performance.

imageDownloadsInProgress, a mutable dictionary, still has all of its data even if you back out. It has become a different question now, how do I delete imageDownloadsInProgress if a user hits back or strays from the current view.

imageDownloadsInProgress is retained, but I added [imagesDownloadsInProgress release] in the dealloc method, however I don't think that runs.

```
-(void)startEventImageDownload:(WhatsonEvent *)eventRecord forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{     

    EventImageDownloader *imageDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if(imageDownloader == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",eventRecord.title);
        imageDownloader = [[EventImageDownloader alloc] init];
        imageDownloader.eventRecord = eventRecord;
        imageDownloader.indexPathInTableView = indexPath;
        imageDownloader.delegate = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:imageDownloader forKey:indexPath];
        [imageDownloader startDownload];
        [imageDownloader release];

        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the self.imageDownloadsInProgess = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] was placed in the ViewDidLoad method with the intention of resetting the dictionary every time. However, if you place the code within a view pushed onto a navigation controller, the ViewDidLoad only executes the first time (I'm not positive that is the case). I added the line to ViewWillAppear since it runs every time the view is placed on screen.

Answer (score 1):

The way I do it is to build my own cache and save the images in the user documents directory. When I call `[tableView reloadData]` (you are calling that, right?) it first checks for each cell if the image is there locally, otherwise it will lazily load them from the feed. Tell me if you need code for this.

Comment: this is the best way to handle it probably if you are using your own stuff. I personally use EGOImageLoader (google it) and the accompanying EGOCache and it works beautifully.

Comment: Anyway - you can call `reloadData` in your `viewDidAppear` method - that should fix it.

Comment: thanks I just tried that and it is still happening. I dont get it, when I back out my self.list becomes nil, and then I have to load the data again. It should be as if loading for the first time since the table should have no information? It must be retaining something.

Comment: may I see your code? I dont think I'm using Apple's code improperly, but it seems they didnt take into account someone reloading the table?